# How to work with RVM on a system with installed Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm

I have installed Ruby (2.3.1) and Rails (5.0.0) with gem v2.6.4 on Arch Linux. Recently I've had need of working with Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.6, so I tried to install RVM with these steps:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$ source /home/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$ rvm install ruby-2.3.0
$ rvm use 2.3.0
```

I restarted my PC and in my shell tried to install rails with this:

```
$ rvm rubygems current
```

I got this message:

> Installed rubygems 2.5.1 is newer than 2.4.8 provided with installed
>   ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.

After that, when I run this command:

```
$ rails -v
```

I got:

> /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby_executable_hooks’: No such file or directory

Supposedly this code resolved the problem (I don't know really what I'm doing):

```
$ sudo gem install --user-install executable-hooks
```

It seems I cannot install an old version of rails, so how to work this $#@&~$ RVM? The documentation in RVM is lacking for me. This should be easy like virtualenv for Python.

Other questions:

- What are the RVM gemsets for?
- When y HOW to use them under my situation?
- Must I add this code `source /home/warcayac/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in my `.bashrc` file?

Please, any help because I am starting to miss Windows @_@!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are doing, but using rvm is just a matter of running their install script and then using `rvm install 2.3.0` and `rvm use 2.3.0`, not sure why you are running that rubygems command. Also you clearly never run Ruby on Windows for long enough if you say that. I did and Ruby can't work in that environment.

Comment: As I said "the documentation in RVM is lacking for me", I am following a video-tutorial (year 2015). So how to install Rails 4.2.6? may you recommend a full tutorial step by step?

Comment: Follow the two commands in homepage, then `rvm install 2.3.0` and `rvm use 2.3.0`. From this point, just use ruby (and gem) like you would normally do. `gem install rails` is enough, if you want a specific version use bundler or `gem install --version 4.x.x`, like normal ruby environment

Comment: Being in Ruby (2.3.1) /Rails (5.0.0) from system I decompressed a RoR project (named "AnyProject") whose Gemfile uses Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.6, I entered this directory "AnyProject" and I got hits message:

RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore ~/Projects/RubyRails/AnyProject/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

Comment: So RVM switched automatically to Ruby 2.3.0, that's OK, but when I run "rails -v" to check the Rails version being used I get this message:

~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'

When I leave that directory, I returned to Ruby/Rails from system, and all is OK over there. My system has these versions installed for Rails gem: 5.0.0 , 4.2.6
What's going on?

Comment: Taking in consideration "just use ruby (and gem) like you would normally do", I run "bundle install --without production" into "AnyProject" directory and I got a error message about bundler; so I installed it "gem install bundler" and re-run "bundle install --without production", it installed several gems (I suppose gems from Gemfile), and I run again "rails -v" and all is OK now. I'm gonna test it further for an error.

Comment: Pending questions:

- What are the RVM gemsets for?

- When y HOW to use them under my situation?

- Must I add this code source /home/warcayac/.rvm/scripts/rvm in my .bashrc file?

Comment: This post answered some questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689180/why-should-i-care-about-rvms-gemset-feature-when-i-use-bundler

Comment: This video also answered some questions: https://youtu.be/BWio5ZquplI

Comment: Ignore ruby gemsets, the main thing you are missing is when you are in your project, you must run _any_ command with prefix `bundle exec`, so `bundle exec rails -v`, `bundle exec rails c`, `bundle exec ruby whatever.rb`

Comment: Also, you probably have a .ruby-version file somewhere, that's why rvm is picking the right ruby version

Answer (score 0):

I recommend either of the two options:

1) removing all **rvm** files, then reinstall **rvm**:

- [How do I upgrade RVM when the official way doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157242/how-do-i-upgrade-rvm-when-the-official-way-doesnt-work/38158619#38158619)

—OR—

2) remove all **rvm** files, then install **rbenv**:

- https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation

> Compatibility note: rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure
>   to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell
>   initialization files before installing rbenv.

---

**UPDATE**

I've used **rvm** in the past, but currently I use **rbenv** on OS X. After installing **rbenv** on Linux, installing Ruby would probably look like:

```
$ rbenv install --list
Available versions:
 1.8.5-p113
 1.8.5-p114
 […]
 2.3.1
 2.4.0-dev
 jruby-1.5.6
 […]
$ rbenv install 2.3.1
[…]
```

Set the global version:

```
$ rbenv global 2.3.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

Set the local version of your repo by adding .ruby-version to your repo's root dir:

```
$ cd ~/whatevs/projects/new_repo
$ echo "2.3.1" > .ruby-version
```